# Trying to update column values in SQL Server leads to error?

Tags: sql-server

I have a column (`attr14` : having `decimal(10,5)` as type) in an SQL server table that has many NULL values that i want to replace with 0 values, in SQL Server i execute a query like this :

```
UPDATE [myds].[dbo].[mytable]
SET [myds].[dbo].[mytable].[attr14] = 0
WHERE [myds].[dbo].[mytable].[attr14] = NULL;
```

But that lead to the following error :

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

if i run :

```
 UPDATE [myds].[dbo].[mytable]
    SET [myds].[dbo].[mytable].[attr14] = 0.0
    WHERE [myds].[dbo].[mytable].[attr14] = NULL;
```

> 0 lines were affected

Then no line is affected while there is NULL values in the `attr14` column

Comment: What do you mean by `many empty cells values` ? Basically the error means  you cannot convert `''` to `decimal(10,5)`

Comment: How can a `decimal(10,5)` be "empty"? Do you mean `NULL`? If so, then the value is *already* `NULL` so it makes no sense trying to set it's value to a `NULL`. As for the error, it's telling you the problem; `''` is *not* a valid `decimal` value.

Comment: If the type is `decimal(10, 5)`, there cannot be "empty cells". The error is telling you that `''` cannot be converted to `decimal(10, 5)` -- what you see as "empty cells" must be another value; quite possibly it's `NULL` already, converted by whatever front-end you're using to an empty string. `decimal` is actually a bit unusual here in that most other numeric types do have a conversion from `''`, but they'll end up converting to `0`, not `NULL`.

Comment: Side note: [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/). Alias your objects in the `FROM` and use those to qualify your columns or, in this case, simply omit the qualifications.

Comment: Sorry yes you are right, i was trying to convert NULL values (empty cells) to something that bypass KeyNotFound constraint in SQL Server, then how to do that ? See update of question i try with 0

Comment: For your edited code `= NULL` is incorrect. You would need to check `IS NULL`. Also the error message in your question no longer seems correlated to the query in your question

Comment: Yes Martin that was it ! thanks !

Comment: And, like I mentioned, fix those qualifiers, @PatrickSchulz . `[myds].[dbo].[mytable].[attr14]` should just be `attr14` in that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column attr14 is of datatype decimal(10,5) then you can try like this.

```
USE [myds]

UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
    SET [attr14] = 0.0
    WHERE [attr14] IS NULL;
```